# try catch block with if condition is not working in selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriver

`if` condition within `try` block does not work.

Script execution is always going out of the `try catch` loop even if the element (defined with Xpath) is present/displayed in the Web page. `if` condition fails.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
try
{
    string path = "//*@id='form_780_0']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div";
    if(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(path)).Displayed) 
    {
        Assert.Fail("Fails");
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //There is nothing here
}

// Some code here and this is executed after evaluating if condition
// even if element is displayed
```

Comment: What does the exception tell you?

Comment: Remove the try and catch. Let it fail and post the complete exception

Comment: @RufusL: I updated my question. Execution does not go into exception path either. it goes out of try catch loop after evaluating if condition.

Comment: @BobGeiger: I suspect its not evaluating to true even though element is present in the screen. hence its going out of the loop. But i have no clue why.

Comment: I would guess that your xpath criteria is incorrect then.  Can you locate it by ID?  If so, and if you are using chrome, you can open the developer tools (F12) and use it's xpath extraction tool on the control you're attempting to locate to pull a valid criteria (at least for Chrome).  Check out http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp and look for the XPath table.  Some browsers interpret xpath very differently.

Comment: @BobGeiger: I figured out why the findElement by xpath was not evaluating to true in my case as explained above: The element that i was trying to locate is a modal pop-up and it is not in the parent web page. Even though the element is seen on screen, the test script fails to detect it. I tried alert.Accept() also, but in vain. Yet to find a solution to this..

Comment: This question could really use a sample of the XML being queried.

Answer (score 0):

"Execution does not go into exception path either. it goes out of try catch loop after evaluating if condition"

- This means that the element is found, but it is NOT displayed. If it was not found you would have gottten a NoSuchElementException. Furthermore, if the element was found, and also displayed, you would trigger the Assert.Fail method